# Getting errors in Upgrading to Log4j2 from Log4j1.2

Tags: log4j2

I'm trying to upgrade Log4j2 from Log4j1.2 but I'm getting below error when I start the server.

```
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [WebappClassLoader
  context: 
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@7e0b0338
] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender" was loaded by [WebappClassLoader
  context: 
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@7e0b0338
].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "turbine".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.console
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "console".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.mqstaging
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "mqstaging".
```

I'm upgrade Log4j jar from version 1.2.17 to 2.19.0

Comment: The messages suggest that: 1. you kept Log4j 1.2 on your classpath, 2. you modified your Log4j 1.2 configuration to use Log4j 2 components. This could not possibly work, since Log4j 1.2 and Log4j2 are incompatible. Cf. [migration from Log4j 1.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) for migration instructions.

Comment: No. I had modified classpath to use Log4j2. But I had different jar which might have dependency on Log4j jar. I think this jar is causing the issue. But I couldn't able find the jar which is compatible to Log4j2. The jar I had is **oss-org-apache-log4j-1.2.14.jar**

Comment: Yes, that probably contains a copy of Log4j 1.2 and you should remove it. As described in the link I gave before, [`log4j-1.2-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api) contains a replacement for Log4j 1.2, that forwards everything to Log4j 2.